# Regex OR expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex expressions and to python. How can I write a script in python where  it finds multiple spaces or tabs and replace them with single space .. how do I write `or` expression?

I wrote the line below for multiple spaces , how do i include the tab too?

```
ModCon = re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', content)
```

Comment: Your code should work fine.

Comment: You can read in the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) that `\s` includes all whitespace characters, including spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 3):

To OR characters, you can just use a character class:

```
content = re.sub("[ \t]{2,}", " ", content)
```

You can OR arbitrary expressions with parentheses and vertical bar:

```
content = re.sub("( |\t){2,}", " ", content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ModCon = re.sub('(\ |\t)+', ' ', content)
```

If there is one or more spaces or tabs, it becomes only one

Comment: Will this include the tab too \t ?

Comment: \s includes tab characters, but I have included it manually (with \t, but it's not neccessary)

Comment: Check python doc for regex as @TillHelgeHelwig mentioned in your question comments. `\s` covers all white space characters, which are `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, where new line and carriage return characters are included too.

Comment: \s includes also new line delimiters. I have just updated my answer. Check it out please!

Comment: I just wrote this expression which i think means all none white space characters , and not \r\n that are repeater for 2 or more times   ModCon = re.sub('[^\S\r\n]{2,}', ' ', content)

Comment: why does it leave the tab ? .. a tab is a white space character .. is there something i did wrong

Comment: i modified it to this which works for single tabs ... it seems that because i had {2,} .. it only looked for 2 tab spaces ModCon = re.sub('[^\S\r\n]+', ' ', content)

Comment: This expression only get not `\S\r\n` characters that *are repeated 2 times*. If you have 2 tabs, it will take it, but not in the other way